# how to do OR search in nutch?

Tags: search, nutch

Say,search for results whose Field is 'A' or 'B'?

it seems the default is AND.

Answer (score 0):

Never worked with Nutch actively, but since it's based on Lucene, shouldn't Lucene's rules apply? That is to say, the [Query Parser Syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Boolean%20operators) should be applicable. See if this helps.

Comment: seems not,I've tried that days ago,or you can try it out here:
http://file.jobirn.com:8080/ROOT-resume

Comment: probably you're right. do have a look at: http://blog.tcg.com/tcg/2009/03/adding-the-boolean-operator-or-to-nutch.html. seems there's a patch for it.

Comment: Thanks,let me try it.
BTW,are you familiar with Query.parse(queryString, queryLang, nutchConf)?

Do you know which fields are searched by this API call?

Answer (score 0):

i was recently started working with nutch .you need to modify the query.java in nutch to get OR query exicuted.
Add the code in Query.java

public void addShouldTerm(String term, String field) {
        clauses.add(new Clause(new Term(term), field, false, false, this.conf));
    }

public void addShouldTerm(String term) {
        addShouldTerm(term, Clause.DEFAULT_FIELD);
    }

and form your query like

Query query= new Query(conf);
query.addNotRequiredTerm("A");
query.addNotRequiredTerm("B");
you will get the results for A Or B.

Please correct me if any other way of doing or better way.

Answer (score 0):

Never used nutch for querying (just for indexing), but the schmea.xml should conatin a defaultOperator which can be set to AND or OR.